# I need the next letter to return, if it is Z, return A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I need the next letter to return, if it is Z, return A

The formula I'm using is this:

```vb
=IF(CHAR(CODE(MID(Col_Ref!$E2,2,1))+1)>90,CHAR(65),CHAR(CODE(MID(Col_Ref!$E2,2,1))+1))
```

Comment: What's the value is Col_Ref!$E2?

Answer (score 0):

As you have written the formula, it will always look in $E$2 and produce the same result until E2 gets changed.

Now the range you have is `90-65` => 25, so:

`=CHAR(MOD(CODE(E2)-64,25)+65)` will

- read out the CODE,
- subtract 64
- strip it to the range,
- then add 65 (in effect add `1` due to the diff; 65-64)

*Might possibly need to be adjusted to produce CHAR(90)*

The worksheet reference and MID() was left out intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula's logic vis-a-vis the `>90` part is fine in that you will get characters from 65 to 90 so all 26 of them.

One problem is in the use of the `CHAR` function. If you look carefully, you will see you are using it to find NOT the code value of the 2nd character in $E2, but rather character associated with it and are then comparing that to 90. So basically `"D">90` is the comparison, not `68>90`. Excel considers any supported language's letter character to be greater than its numerical characters. (Now there's nuance in that, so a Latin "D" may not be considered greater than in value than an Arabic numeral 6, but I assume you are not concerned with that!)

Therefore, any character it returns will generate `TRUE` as all are considered greater than 90.

To avoid that, you can:

1. Be very careful with writing the formula, or
2. Use the `IF` to deal with numerical values (`CODE` results) ONLY, and place it inside a `CHAR` function. That way there's no need to be really, really careful.

Like this:

```
=CHAR(  IF( CODE(MID(Col_Ref!$E2, 2, 1)) > 89,  65,  CODE(MID(Col_Ref!$E2, 2, 1)) + 1)  )
```

Smaller issue, since the character "Z" has a value of 90, notice that no letter found (uppercase letter found) will trigger rolling back around to "A"... you need to use 89, not 90 (or change from `>` to `>=`), as, while you may have aimed at your range including all 26 letters, you really want to see if `Z > 89`, which can happen, and will give you the desired "A", not to see if `Z > 90`, which will never happen, and so you will get unfortunate results.

Side issue, but since you seem to want uppercase letter to be found and returned, you might encounter a "real world" situation in which the letter in place 2 is a lower case "r", perhaps, or even some more unfortunate value. `CODE` will return the lowercase value in that... case... and you might not like the result. If you place the `Col_Ref!$E2` references inside an `UPPER` function, you can get a quality result for someone's little goof instead of failure. (So, `UPPER(Col_Ref!$E2)`:  this is called "wrapping it in a (fill in the name) function.")